# How to define a variable in Azure Devops Pipeline as a sequence of element?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I **cannot** define a variable in Azure DevOps pipeline yaml file ***as a sequence of strings***.

**Azure DevOps** raised the following error when I try to run new.

```
Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/vars.yaml (Line: X, Col: XX): A sequence was not expected
/vars.yaml (Line: Y, Col: YY): A sequence was not expected
```

My template file

```
# File: vars.yaml
variables:

    debugMailingList: ["A1@a.com", "A2@a.com", "A3@a.com", "A4@a.com", "A5@a.com"]
    officialMailingList: ["B1@b.com", "B2@b.com", "B3@b.com", "B4@b.com", "B5@b.com"]
```

I would like to define the content of the variables as a list.

Comment: Did you try the ["name value" syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#specify-variables)?

Comment: Yep, I thought about it but is not what I need, consider that in pipeline I would use the variable as a list of mail addresses (a list of stings). Name/value for each address does not make sense in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in Azure Pipelines are always just strings. You can use the expression functions to split them.

- [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split)

```
variables:
- name: environments
  value: |
    jesse@example.org, charlotte@example.org,
    lily-rose@example.org, mika-charlie@example.org

steps:  
  - ${{ each env in split(variables.environments, ',')}}:
    - script: ./deploy.sh --environment ${{ env }}
```

Or put the whole json structure in the variable and then parse it in your steps using the constructs of the scripting language of choice.

```
Convert-FromJson -raw $env:debugMailingList
```

If it's just for readability, consider putting the email addresses in a multi-line string:

```
variables:
  - name: "emailaddresses"
    value: |
      jesse@example.org
      charlotte@example.org
      lily-rose@example.org
      mika-charlie@example.org
```

Or combine the comma separated list and the multi-line string:

```
variables:
  - name: "emailaddresses"
    value: |
      jesse@example.org, charlotte@example.org,
      lily-rose@example.org, mika-charlie@example.org
```